# $f(x) = \int_{k=0}^x e^{f(k)}\, dk$

Tags: integration

I have the function
$$f(x) = \int\limits_{k=0}^x e^{f(k)} dk$$

How can I solve for an explicit formula of $f$? In my current solution, it becomes undefined past a certain value of $x$

**Atempts:** Taking a derivative, we have
$$f'(x) = e^f(x)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln f'(x) = f(x)$$
Taking a second derivative,
$$\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)} = f'(x)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$f'(x)^2 = f''(x)$$
Similarly,
$$f^{(n)}(x) = (n-1)!f'(x)^n$$

Now, by the Taylor expansion (and substituting $g(x)=f'(x)$):
$$g(x) = g(0)+xg'(0)+\frac12x^2g''(0)+\cdots$$
$$=g(0)+xg(0)^2+x^2g(0)^3+\cdots$$
$$=g(0)[1+xg(0)+x^2g(0)^2+\cdots]$$
$$=\frac{g(0)}{1-xg(0)}$$
Therefore,
$$f(x)=\int g(x) = \int \frac{f'(0)}{1-xf'(0)}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow$$

### $$f(x) = f(0)-ln(1-xf'(0))$$

So, it seems I have a solution. But what happens when $x>\frac{1}{f'(0)}?$

**PS**: Original problem is from ocw, #2 on this link:
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-01sc-classical-mechanics-fall-2016/assignments/MIT8_01F16_pset4.pdf

In this case, $f'(0) < 0$, and $x\ge 0$, hence $f(x)$ is always defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this much more simply. First you read off the original integral equation also the initial condition $f(0)=0$.

Then by the method of separation of variables
$$
f'(x)=e^{f(x)}\implies e^{-f(x)}f'(x)=1\\
\implies e^{-f(x)}-e^{-f(0)}=-x,\\f(x)=-\ln(1-x).
$$

Comment: I don't see how you got the middle equation.

Comment: @programjames, The second implication follows from applying the fundamental theorem of calculus to $(e^{-f})' = -f' e^{-f}$, or equivalently $\int f' e^{-f} \, \mathrm{d}x = -e^{-f} + \mathsf{const}$. Also, this answer tells that there is no way we can 'naturally' extend $f$ beyond $x < 1$. This kind of blow-up phenomenon is quite common in ODE business.